# PayPal automation with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, paypal

I am trying to automate withdraw of funds from PayPal using Selenium (C#). I did manage to go over all the steps (login, switch to wallet, start withdraw), but I got stuck in the form where the amount should be entered.

The element looks like this:

```
<input id="amount" name="amount"
       class="hasHelp js_needsValidation  validate amount-input nemo_amountInput EUR"
       required="required" aria-required="true" value="" placeholder="Amount" dir="ltr"
       pattern="[^\d]*(\d{0,3}){1}(\&nbsp;\d{3})*(\,\d{2})+[^\d]*"
       min="2,00&nbsp;EUR" max="5,00&nbsp;EUR" data-decimal-separator=","
       data-separator="&nbsp;/" aria-invalid="false" type="text">
```

I did manage to add a text into this element but when I click on the commit button nothings happen. It appears that there is some kind of validation done when the value is typed in which I'm missing.

The element is declared as property in a class like this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "amount")] 
public IWebElement TxtAmount { get; set; }
```

... and I add text to the element in a function like this:

```
public static void ElementEnterText(this IWebElement element, string value) 
{ 
element.SendKeys(value);
}
```

Is it possible to see from the element what I am missing?

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have to enter the text in the input?

Comment: Isn't there too much code. Have the element declared as property in a class like this:

 <code>[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "amount")]
 public IWebElement TxtAmount { get; set; }</code>

... and I add text to the element in a function like this:

public static void ElementEnterText(this IWebElement element, string value)
        {
            element.SendKeys(value);
        }

Comment: how the *beep* can I mark something as code in a comment!?

Comment: just edit the original post

Comment: Now my post looks great any suggestion and/or solution for the problem?